# ASP gridview event customizable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have that kind of gridview with automatic events :

```
<asp:GridView BackColor="Beige" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Azure" ID="grvMandat" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowUpdating="grvMandat_RowUpdate" OnRowEditing="grvMandat_OnRowEditing" runat="server" Visible="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="Aucun Article"  >
```

OnRowEditing event make it possible to edit the datas of a sql table.

what is anoying is that i have to click twice on the edit button to trigger any textbox to appaer.

Any idea of the reason why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is default behavior for GridView.

What you want to do to achieve one-click edit mode is to add attribute to each of your grid view rows to respond to one click.

```
row.Attributes["onclick"] =
                        ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Edit$" + row.DataItemIndex, true);
```

There is a good post on how to do this here: http://forums.asp.net/t/2012153.aspx?inline+gridview+edit+without+edit+just+on+click+of+cell

*****EDIT******
After further clarification from OP, I think the problem lies within the RowEditing event.

```
Private Sub grvMandat_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles grvMandat.RowEditing
grvMandat.DataSource = CType(Session("grvMandat"), DataView)
grvMandat.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
grvMandat.DataBind()
End Sub
```

EDIT the reel thing is here :

```
protected void grvMandat_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grvMandat.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    ShowGrv();
}
```

Comment: I suppose normaly i have to select the row first, then i can chose to edit it ? @PeonProgrammer

Comment: hmm...can you show me your code for the pageload event and also the RowEditing event?

Comment: page load just affect a table to my grid view (dataSource() dataBind()) and rowEditing is empty...

Comment: Wait, this is visual basic ? @PeonProgrammer   i'm in C#... maybe i can translate it.

Comment: awrigth, it was  : grvMandat.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

            showGrv(); show gridview just call data bind function

Comment: Just accept the edit @PeonProgrammer no one will see the changes elseway, and thank you !